# Getting Play button to play a stream link

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic4

Just started using Ionic 4 and Angular so a very new beginner :)

I bought a UI Template from code canyon but never realised I had to code the music playing part of it.  Anyway I have been searching to get a stream playing but failed.  I found a post which said to just use a HTML5 code to stream music.

When I click Play the music never plays.  Where am I going wrong ? My player.page.ts looks like this :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-player',
    templateUrl: './player.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./player.page.scss'],

})
export class PlayerPage implements OnInit {

    @Input() data: any;

    stream: any = null;
    valueVolume = 50;


    constructor( public modalController: ModalController) { }
    audio: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.audio = new Audio();
        this.audio.src = 'http://tbvr.noip.me:8000/';
        this.audio.load();
    }

    clickButtonMusic() {
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.modalController.dismiss();
    }

    playAudio() {
        this.audio.play();
        this.audio.loop = false;
    }

    stopAudio() {
        this.audio.pause();
    }

    volumen(event) {

        this.valueVolume = event.detail.value;
        this.stream.volume = this.valueVolume / 100;

    }
}
```

and my player.page.html looks like this :

```html
<ion-header no-border>
 <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start" class="chevron">
   <ion-button
    class=" circle-button ion-no-padding"
    fill="clear"
    shape="round"
    color="default"
    (click)="closeModal()"
   >
    <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
   </ion-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title> Live Now</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="ion-text-center">
 <div class="h-100  vertical-align">
  <div
   class="image-container"
   [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ data?.photo +')'}"
  ></div>
  <div class="py">
   <h4>{{ data?.title }}</h4>
   <p>{{ data?.text }}</p>
  </div>
  <ion-buttons>
   <ion-button
    class="media-button circle-button ion-no-padding"
    fill="clear"
    size="large"
    shape="round"
    color="default"
   >
    <i class="icon-share-2"></i>
   </ion-button>


   <ion-button class="play-button" (click)="playAudio()"></ion-button> 
   <ion-button class="stop-button"  (click)="stopAudio()"></ion-button>
   

   <ion-button
    class="media-button circle-button ion-no-padding"
    fill="clear"
    size="large"
    shape="round"
    color="default"
   >
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
   </ion-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-range
   min="0"
   max="100"
   color="secondary"
   [value]="valueVolume"
   (ionChange)="volumen($event)"
  >
   <ion-label slot="start">
    <i class="icon-volume-1"></i>
   </ion-label>
   <ion-label slot="end">
    <i class="icon-volume-2"></i>
   </ion-label>
  </ion-range>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks for any help anyone can give me.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ionic Cordova native plugins. These plugins are available in Ionic framework website.Install the plugin and follow the simple instructions provide in the doc for activating the plugin. Some plugins want special permission to work in Ios(eg:Geocoder). So kindly read the doc carefully.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio

Here I am attaching the link of Ionic Native audio player plugin link. Don't forget to import the plugin in app.module.ts file after successfull installation , otherwise it will start to show error like `staticInjectError`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to play fine.

audio: any; needed moving to onInit

Just that when I hit stop the music stops but seems to still be downloading from the server.